# How to optimize images to imporve website performance in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, webpack, seo

I am currently working on a website with the use of React.js. The website includes an automatic imageslider/carousel which is really effecting the performance of the website and slows it down significantly.

I have the following code for the image slider:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import images from "../../constants/images";
import "../CSS/carousel.css";
import { BsArrowLeft, BsArrowRight } from "react-icons/bs";

const carouselImages = [
  images.carousel_one,
  images.carousel_two,
  images.carousel_three,
  images.carousel_four,
  images.carousel_five,
  images.carousel_six,
  images.carousel_seven,
  images.carousel_eight,
  images.carousel_nine,
  images.carousel_ten,
  images.carousel_eleven,
  images.carousel_twelve,
  images.carousel_thirteen,
  images.carousel_fourteen,
];

const Carousel = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const slideInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrent((current) =>
        current < carouselImages.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0
      );
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearInterval(slideInterval);
  }, []);
  const length = carouselImages.length;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };

  if (!Array.isArray(carouselImages) || carouselImages.length <= 0) {
    return null;
  }

  const switchIndex = (index) => {
    setCurrent(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app__carousel">
      <div className="app__carousel-inner_container">
        {carouselImages.map((slide, index) => (
          <div
            className={
              index === current
                ? "app__carousel-slide_active"
                : "app__carousel-slide"
            }
            key={index}
          >
            {index === current && (
              <img src={slide} className="app__carousel-image" />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
        <BsArrowLeft onClick={prevSlide} className="app__carousel-left_arrow" />
        <BsArrowRight
          onClick={nextSlide}
          className="app__carousel-right_arrow"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="app__carousel-indicator_container">
        {carouselImages.map((_, index) => (
          <button
            className={`app__carousel-indicator_btn${
              current === index ? " active" : ""
            }`}
            onClick={() => switchIndex(index)}
          ></button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

I have already used the 'imagemin' plugin along with a craco.config.js file to try to optimize the images. My craco file looks like this:

```
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      webpackConfig.optimization.minimize = true;
      webpackConfig.optimization.minimizer.push(
        new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
          minimizer: {
            implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
            options: {
              plugins: [["mozjpeg", { quality: 85 }]],
            },
          },
          generator: [
            {
              preset: "webp",
              implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminGenerate,
              options: {
                plugins: [
                  "imagemin-webp",
                  "imagemin-pngquant",
                  "imagemin-svgo",
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        })
      );
      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

Another thing that I have done is encoded the images with WebP by running

```
npm i imagemin-webp -D
```

and importing my images as shown below:

```
import carousel_one from "../assets/carousel_one.jpg?as=webp";
```

The steps which I have already taken have only improved the performance by a few points in the lighthouse testing. Is there anything else that can be added or imporved in the already existing code to improve the performance more?

Answer (score 0):

You can further optimize images by using AVIF instead of WEBP, which in most cases should offer even better compression than WEBP with the same image quality. If you want to push this step further, there are AI compressors available online, that are able to shrink the size without loosing quality even further (This you will either have to do manually each time you want to shrink image size, or in most instances pay for API).

Another option is to serve images that are the minimum required size for the resolution you are using. This means either using `<picture>` or `srcset` attribute, or making your own solution in JavaScript.

But the most common solution to pictures slowing down page remain lazy loading.